# Faster way of calculating a distance matrix with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am calculating a matrix with numpy/scipy like this:

```
cost = np.empty([chroma1.data.shape[1], chroma2.data.shape[1]])

for x, cx in enumerate(chroma1.transpose()):
    for y, cy in enumerate(chroma2.transpose()):
        cost[x, y] = sp.distance.euclidean(cx, cy)
```

This takes quite an amount of time. Is there any numpy/scipy function that would allow me to get rid of the two nested loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're calculating a distance matrix.  `scipy.spatial.distance` contains several specialized, optimized functions for doing exactly that.

In your case:

```
cost = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(chroma1.T, chroma2.T)
```

should do exactly what you want.